# Can't detect wireless networks in Ubuntu 10.04 on a Sony VAIO VPCM121AX

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, sony-vaio

I just recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 on a Sony VAIO VPCM121AX and I can't detect wireless networks! Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the output of command lspci here? I tried to search your laptop hardware details here http://b2b.sony.com/Solutions/product/VPCM121AX/P but could not find the chipset details.